# How can I add borders to the result?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am copying three cells from Spreadsheet 1 to the last row of Spreadsheet 2. Now I want to set borders on those three cells in Spreadsheet 2.

I have already tried duplicating the first part of the last line in my script, then adding a setBorder command, but no borders were written on to Spreadsheet 2.

Here is the code that I'm using:

```
function copyRange() {
 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('this is spreadsheet 1 ID');
 var ss = sss.getSheets()[0];
 var range = ss.getRange('C318:E318'); 
 var data = range.getValues();

 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(''this is spreadsheet 2 ID');
 var ts = tss.getSheets()[0];

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,1,3).setValues(data);

 }
```

While the values of the range C318:E318 are copied over properly, I don't know how I can add borders. Can anyone help?

Comment: Take a look at [range.setBorder()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setBorder(Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean,Boolean))

Comment: Cooper, I looked at the setBorder documentation, then added the following line at the bottom of my script:  ts.getLastRow(), 1,1,3).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true);   Now, I'm getting the following error:   Missing ; before statement. (line 11, file "Code"). What should I have learned from the documentation that I obviously did not learn? What is this error trying to tell this crazy person and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: [Edit] to show the latest script and the error.

Comment: If there was something that I needed to read, I totally missed it...

Comment: Edit your script to show the code now that you've added `setBorder()`, the error you're getting just means that you're not closing a statement properly somewhere.

Comment: Jescanellas: Thank you for your reply.  Your code worked beautifully. I did see two problems, though. The line  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('this is spreadsheet 1 ID'); is actually a line of code, followed by a comment. Somehow the comment symbol went somewhere. The actual line should be var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXX'); // ('this is spreadsheet 1'). The same error is in the line var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(''this is spreadsheet 2 ID');. The line should be var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('XXXXX'); // ('this is spreadsheet 2').

Comment: (Had to write this in two comments, because SO said that this was too long.) Now for a theory question: In the code, 3 cells are selected to copy ('C318:E318'). In the last line, 3 cells are copied over (ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,1,3). AFAIK, these two ranges must match to prevent a fatal failure. How can I copy 3 cells over, but put borders on a greater number of cells?

Comment: Thought of another situation: (Will post another question, if needed.) I've got another list that needs to be copied to another spreadsheet, but the list is variable in length (sometimes it's 15 lines, sometimes 22, sometimes...) The list builder put the list length in a cell using a =COUNT() function. How can I copy this list over?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your line:

```
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(''this is spreadsheet 2 ID');
```

It should be:

```
var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('this is spreadsheet 2 ID');
```

The rest of the code is correct. You can add borders at the end of the getRange function, like this:

```
 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1,1,3).setValues(data).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
```